# SQ Server 2008 r2 Reporting Services : optional parameter values and reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

In an existing ssrs 2008 r2 report, I have a requirement from a user where they want to add 2 more parameters to the report. Right now there is an option

where the user can choice to generate report1, report2, report3, report4, report5, report6, report7, report8, and/or any combination of the reports I just listed.

This is setup by using an expression in the visibility property for each of the 8 tablixes.

For your information, the following is an example of how to display one of the reports or not:

```
=iif(InStr(join(Parameters!report.Value,","),6)>0,false,true)
```

Now the user wants to be able to add the parameters of customer and inventory_item based upon if report7 and/or or report8 is selected.

Now can you tell me the following:

1. Would you show me the code I can use in the dataset to select report7 and/or report8?
2. Is this considered using 'optional' parameters since they new parameters of inventory_item are based upon if report7 and/or or report8 is selected. If so, can you show me how I can code for these optional parameters?
3. If the above is not possible to select specific reports, then would the dataset query need to look something like: 
   `where @report is null or where @report is not null`? What would you suggest?
4. If the above options are not possible for the 2 new parameters, would I have all items (or one item)selected so that the reports would run all the time?

Comment: Do you mean if the customer selects report 7 or report 8 he wants to see in addition to what is currently displayed the Customer and Inventory_Item tablixes?

Answer (score 0):

For your extra parameters, you can check out **Cascading Parameters** (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3466/cascaded-parameters-in-sql-server-reporting-services/).

Basically, you'll add your new parameters but not use them for the filter unless reports 7 or 8 is selected. Unfortunately, there's not a method I know of to disable a parameter based on another parameter selection.

I'm guessing from your expression that your **Report** parameter just returns a value of 1 - 8 based on the report selected. The example should be from Report 6:

```
=IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!report.Value, ","), 6) > 0, false, true)
```

The **Filter** to use your new **inventory_item** parameter would be something like:

```
=IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!report.Value, ","), "7") > 0
 OR  InStr(Join(Parameters!report.Value, ","), "8") > 0, 
 IIF(Parameters!inventory_item.Value = Fields!inventory_item.Value, TRUE, FALSE), TRUE)
```

This would only restrict the data by inventory_item if the report is 7 or 8.